# How to get keys and values from JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js

I have a JavaScript array that I am attempting to extract teams (Team A, Team B) and put them into an array and then put duty into a separate array while keeping the order.
Below details current array output, JS code shows and expected result

Array:

```
[
  {
    "Team A": 2,
    "Team B": 3
  }
]
```

JS:

```
  var retValue = [];  
  var count = this.jsonArray.map((cv) => {
    var teams = cv["teams"].reduce((acc, team) => {
      acc[team["value"]] = team["text"];
      return acc;
    }, {});
    return cv["duty"].reduce((acc, duty) => {
      acc[teams[duty["parentId"]]] = acc[
        teams[duty["parentId"]]
      ]
        ? acc[teams[duty["parentId"]]] + 1
        : 1;
      return acc;
    }, {});
  });

  retValue = Object.keys(count).map((cv) => count[cv]);
  console.debug(retValue);  //working
  
  
  var getKeys = [];
  getKeys = Object.keys(retValue); //not working
   
  var getValues = [];
  ....
```

Expected Result:

```
[Team A, Team B] , [2 , 3]
```

Original JS Array/Object:

```
{
  "jsonArray": [{
    "teams": [

      {
        "text": "Team A",
        "id": 1,
        "value": 500,
        "parentId": 333
      },
      {
        "text": "Team B",
        "id": 2,
        "value": 600,
        "parentId": 444
      }

    ],
    "duty": [

      {
        "text": "Meetings",
        "id": 11,
        "value": 100,
        "parentId": 500
      },
      {
        "text": "Lunch",
        "id": 12,
        "value": 101,
        "parentId": 500
      },
      {
        "text": "Time Cards",
        "id": 13,
        "value": 102,
        "parentId": 600
      },

      {
        "text": "Parking",
        "id": 14,
        "value": 103,
        "parentId": 600

      },
      {
        "text": "Breakfast",
        "id": 15,
        "value": 104,
        "parentId": 600
      }
    ]

  }]
};
```

Comment: Your expected result is not a valid object. It's two separate arrays.

Comment: Do you want a 2-dimensional array, like `[["Team A", "Team B"] , [2 , 3]]`

Comment: What are `2` and `3` in the result? How do they relate to the team names?

Comment: please add awanted result of the larger data set.

Comment: @Barmar Team A has the value 500, and in 'duty' there are two entries with parentID = 500. (equivalent for team B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve it like this:

```js
var retValue = [];
var count = jsonArray.map((cv) => {
  var teams = cv["teams"].reduce((acc, team) => {
    acc[team["value"]] = team["text"];
    return acc;
  }, {});
  return cv["duty"].reduce((acc, duty) => {
    var teamName = teams[duty["parentId"]];
    acc[teamName] = acc[teamName] ? acc[teamName] + 1 : 1;
    return acc;
  }, {});
});

console.debug(count);  // array of team names and their corresponding duty counts.

var getKeys = Object.keys(count[0]);

console.debug(getKeys);  // array of team names

var getValues = Object.values(count[0]); 

console.debug(getValues);  // array of counts
```